# Building a string by repeating a single character

Tags: swift

To size a view, I needed to build a string by repeating a single character. I came up with the following:

```
var str = ""
for _ in 0 ..< length {
    str.append("W")
}
```

I also came up with a functional alternative:

```
let str = (0 ..< digits).reduce("") { (result, _) -> String in
    result + "0" // assuming 0 is the most wide number
}
```

Both feel a bit verbose. Is there a shorter way or a built-in function in Swift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `init(repeating:count:)`

```
var str = String(repeating: "w", count: length)
```